# symphony Call to undefined method App\Controller\UserController::getDoctrine()

Tags: php, symfony

Estoy empesando en symfony 6 y me sale el siguente error:

> Call to undefined method App\Controller\UserController::getDoctrine()

Aquí esta mi código:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class UserController extends AbstractController{

    public function getUsers(){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $listUsers = $em->getRepository('App:Users')->findBy([], ['nombre' => 'ASC']);
        return $this->render('user/users.html.twig', [
            'listUsers'=> $listUsers
        ]);
    }
}
```

¿Alguien sabe como arreglarlo?